# Javascript Global Scope Misinterpretation

Tags: javascript, variables, scope

I've come across this problem often and thought I'd finally ask for an explanation. I have Google Chrome and use the javascript console often. When I declare a global variable I can always access its content in the console but often when I try to access the variable from inside a function when the script runs in the browser I get a "Cannot read property 'top' of undefined" type error.

I'll paste a piece of code here and if someone could explain to me why I get this error I'd very much appreciate it!

```
// JavaScript Document
var myglobalvariable;
// ...

$(document).ready( function() {
  myglobalvariable = document.getElementsByTagName("article");
  // ...
});

function myFunction() {
  for (i in myglobalvariable) {
    mylocalvariable_top = myglobalvariable[i].style.top; // Error points to this line
  // ...
  }
}
```

myFunction will then typically be called by an event handler and report the error mentioned above.

Comment: for in should only be used with objects, not arrays

Comment: off topic: You have all the jQuery helpers available, yet you're not willing to use them?

Comment: @DanLee I had jQuery helpers in my script but it's a pretty performance heavy process I'm running. I googled performance on jQuery helpers and some developers commented that jQuery selectors takes longer to process. So I set about trying to have my script run quicker. Partially doing it this way to learn more about performance.

Comment: @user2307877 Then why bother using a ~90kb library in the first place? Just for DOM ready? There are easier ways to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, best to avoid `for ... in` for arrays.  That said, just to clarify the misunderstanding that is producing this error, you should write:

```
function myFunction() {
  for (i in myglobalvariable) {
    mylocalvariable_top = i.style.top; // <-- i IS the element
                                       // <-- for clarity you should probably rename "i" to
                                       //    "element" or something more descriptive which will
                                       //      make clear it is not a numerical index
  // ...
  }
}
```

That is, it doesn't make sense to do the lookup `myglobalvariable[i]` since in your case `i` already means "the i-th element of the array myglobalvariable"

You are simply mixing up the conventions of a typical `for` loop with those of the `for... in` construct.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that what you are doing is not what you want.

```
for (i in myglobalvariable) { }
```

This does not loop through items in an array but instead keys/property names of an object.

```
myglobalvariable[i]
```

Above you access what ever type the property with that key is.

```
myglobalvariable[i].style.top
```

Above you access the style property of said object. If that object does not have a style property then this will be undefined. Meaning that when you call .top on a property which does not exist you get "Cannot read property 'top' of undefined".

What you are presenting here is a specific problem and not a general "Global Scope Misinterpretation".

**Solution**

```
var i, len = myglobalvariable.length;
for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (myglobalvariable[i].style)
        mylocalvariable_top = myglobalvariable[i].style.top;
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This creates an `NodeList` of nodes.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  myglobalvariable = document.getElementsByTagName("article");
  // ...
});
```

This iterates through each node **and** any additional attributes on the `NodeList` object.

```
function myFunction() {
  for (i in myglobalvariable) {
    mylocalvariable_top = myglobalvariable[i].style.top; // Error points to this line
  // ...
  }
}
```

That said, you can encounter items in `myglobalvariable` that aren't nodes and don't have a `style` attribute. In particular, `i` will be `item` and `length` at some point during iteration.

This will more safely iterate over the list:

```
function myFunction() {
  for (var i = 0; i < myglobalvariable.length; i++) {
    mylocalvariable_top = myglobalvariable[i].style.top; // Error points to this line
  // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` returns a `NodeList`, it is like an `Array` in many ways, but isn't one.

Comment: The above mentioned for loop sorted out the problem. Thank you svidgen :)